# Error : "The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically."

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter

I am facing an error which I do not know how to fix. I'm trying to get this piece of code to work on windows but I have this error appearing

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


plt.plot()
```

> Error: "The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically."

Comment: Is that literally the only code you have?

Comment: yes, that is the only code i have

Comment: Are you using jupyter locally or through a browser (like Kaggle)?

Comment: using jupyter locally

Comment: something installed is corrupt (this includes Jupyter and it's dependencies).  I'd try importing each of the modules by themselves and trying to figure out the culprit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [After conda update, python kernel crashes when matplotlib is used](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69786885/7758804)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had the same error message appear while using Jupyter notebook. Based on what I read, I think it's suggested to reinstall pandas, NumPy and matplotlib (other libraries if necessary) and see if that works.

I had several other issues, so I reinstalled the Anaconda navigator.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use py script instead of Jupyter but if you wanna use Jupyter try either reinstalling NumPy or update.

```
pip install -U numpy
```